# Architecture Spring MVC + angular app

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I have one maybe dummy, question but i really want to find better approach how build Spring app with angular. So essence of the question it's - should i put my front side to folders on java aplication, then deploy single app, or will be better if i create two differend app on java only REST and angular front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on what are you trying to achieve with Angular and what parts of your front-end will be implemented using it.

I'd definitely suggest creating a separate module for every standalone independent feature you're implementing with Angular.

Comment: if i right, high-Loaded app don't use approach with single app?

Answer (score 1):

Spring has a few examples - https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js. You could see the folder structure and the mechanism for unit testing.

Another good resource is https://dzone.com/articles/java-maven-angularjs-seed

jHipster https://jhipster.github.io/ is another good framework which sets up a maven or gradle project with the required project structure for angularjs and spring boot. They however use npm but its worth exploring.